# Modify PKPk of a square waveform

Tags: amplifier, waveform

I'm trying to make a circuit that takes takes 2 input:

1. A DC voltage (3-12 V range)
2. A 5 V (PKPk) square waveform (the frequency doesn't matter)

Then gives as output a voltage with the same frequency of the second input and the PkPk voltage corresponding to the first input.
My first Idea was to use a transistor, I tried to use a NPN BC547B but it was giving me a strange waveform as output.
I've connected the 2nd input to the base (with a 4.7 kΩ resistance) and the 1st to the collector.
Does anyone know what I did wrong or what I could try?

Comment: Welcome! Please show the schematic of your circuit.

Comment: Unipolar or bipolar (0-5V, -2.5V to 2.5V) or some other DC offset? Same goes for the output? Frequency does also matter - at least ballpark - Hz? kHz? MHz? etc.

Comment: Unipolar PKpk and the frequency range goes from 41.5KHz to 299 mHz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a circuit that should do what you want with a few caveats. It sounds from your description that you had something very similar, but many of the caveats are based on the size of R3. A smaller value required more current (in this case supplied from an OpAmp, but allows greater speed and the output is less susceptible to loading. For example, if you had a 1Mohm load at Voutput with a 3V set point, then Voutput would actually be 2.997V (simple potential divider). If your output load was 10k then the peak voltage at Voutput would be 2.727.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgLseZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: There is no need to plug anything to the OFFSET pins?

Comment: Which OFFSET pins are you referring to - offset pins sometimes found on OpAmps or the Vset node?

Comment: I'm refering to the offset pins of OpAmps

Comment: Offset null pins on OpAmps allow the small DC input offset voltage to be removed. Nowadays it is very easy to find an opamp with acceptable input offset voltage without needing to add additional null/calibration circuitry

Comment: Why V+ and V- pins aren't connected?

Comment: Ah ok, you are asking about the power supply pins. It is common to simplify OpAmp schematics by not drawing the power supplies in, or drawing them somewhere else to aid in clarity of the circuit itself. In this design, the OpAmp needs to either powered from a voltage greater than 12V (say 13V or higher) or choose a Rail to Rail Input Output (RRIO) OpAmp and run it from a 12V supply (V+ = 12V, V- = 0V)